# Tkinter changes the wrong button background when button pressed

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

I have an array of buttons, when I press a button the button's position in the array is printed but the color is not changed. Instead the color of the button at the bottom of the respective column is changed. Here I have pressed `0, 0`, `1, 0` & `2, 4`, as can be seen the buttons at the bottom of each column have changed but not the button pressed with the exception of `2, 4`.

How come?

[image]

The code,

```
from tkinter import *

def init():
    print("Started")

class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.text = [[None]*50]*3
        self.buttons = [[None]*50]*3
        frame = Frame(master)
        #frame.pack()
        
        for i in range(3):
            
            for j in range(50):
                
                self.buttons[i][j] = Button(root, command = lambda i=i, j=j : self.led(i, j))
                self.buttons[i][j].config(width = 2, height = 3)
                self.buttons[i][j].grid(row = i, column = j)
        
    def led(self, i, j):
        print(i, j)
        self.buttons[i][j].config(bg = 'blue')
        
        
init()
root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just in case you do not know. Those information seems redundant to archive as tkinter does that anyway. Is there a reason for what you doing there other than have refernces?

Comment: @Thingamabobs not sure I understand your comment

Comment: You could solve this task in different ways and the way you choose seems unreasonable. For example, you could call the constructor of the button and do `button.configure(command= lambda b=button: self.led(b))` this would save you these complicated reference tracking.

Comment: @Thingamabobs ahh right I get you. I need the refenence data as it gets sent to an embedded device via a serial link where it is explicitly used to control an array of LEDs.

Comment: There it comes in what I meant with *tkinter does that anyway* you can retrieve that data with `button.grid_info()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the lines

```
self.text = [[None]*50]*3
self.buttons = [[None]*50]*3
```

your lists contain 3 instances of the `same` array. Using

```
[[None]*50 for _ in range(3)]
```

should create a list that contains 3 different instances of lists.